# Search records on DB in Symfony2

Tags: php, search, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm building a page in Symfony2 that permits me to search a term (e.g. a name of a person) in my Database and show in the same page (even after a page reload) all matching records (e.g. all the person with this name).

This is my anagrafica.html.twig

```
{# src/Acme/MyBundle/Resources/views/Page/anagrafica.html.twig #}
{% extends 'AcmeMyBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <form id="formsearch" name="p" method="get" action="anagrafica">
        <span>
            <input type="text" name="search_name"  id="search_name" />
        </span>
        <input type="image" name="button_search" />
    </form>

    {% for anagrafica in anagrafiche %}
        <article class="blog">
            <div class="date">{{ anagrafica.DataNascita|date('c') }}</div>
            <header>
                <h2><a href="{{ path('AcmeMyBundle_showAnag', { 'id': anagrafica.id }) }}">{{ anagrafica.nome }}</a></h2>
            </header>
            <div class="snippet">
                <p>{{ anagrafica.cognome }}</p>
                <p class="show_complete"><a href="{{ path('AcmeMyBundle_showAnag', { 'id': anagrafica.id }) }}">Show all data</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no entries</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my PageController.php

```
<?php // src/Acme/MyBundle/Controller/PageController.php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PageController extends Controller {
    //...
    public function anagraficaAction() {    
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getEntityManager();

        $anagrafiche = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('b')
            ->from('AcmeMyBundle:Anagrafiche',  'b')
            ->where("b.nome = :nome")
            ->setParameter('nome', 'Alex' )
            ->addOrderBy('b.id', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:Page:anagrafica.html.twig', array('anagrafiche' => $anagrafiche));
    }
}
```

I think I only need to update my PageController.php and replace the name `'Alex' in :
 ->setParameter('nome', 'Alex' )`
with a variable that refers to the entry in my form definied in anagrafica.html.twig.
Anyway I have no idea of how to do this, and a quick search on google and forums do not helped me.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get GET-parameters via

```
$searchName = $request->query->get('search_name');
```

But for this you still need the `$request` variable. You can use it as parameter and change your method signature to this:

```
public function anagraficaAction(Request $request)
```

This way, you can call the `$request` parameter in your method.

The other way is to get the request of the current controller inside your method.

```
$request = $this->get('request');
```

Using this you can change your `setParameter` to this:

```
setParameter('nome', $searchName)
```

Answer (score 0):

change this `setParameter('nome', 'Alex')` to something like `setParameter('nome', $_GET['search_name'])` since this form passing data by using get method.

Comment: correct except in symfony2 the preferred method is: `$request->query->get('name')`; where request object can be fetched using `$request = $this->getRequest();`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I edited my PageController.php such this:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/MyBundle/Controller/PageController.php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:Page:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function infoAction()
    {
       return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:Page:info.html.twig');
    }

    public function anagraficaAction(Request $request)
    {


       $em = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getEntityManager();

$title = $request->get('search_name');


       $anagrafiche = $em->createQueryBuilder()
       ->select('b')
       ->from('AcmeMyBundle:Anagrafiche',  'b')
       ->where("b.nome = :nome")
       ->setParameter('nome', $title )
       ->addOrderBy('b.id', 'DESC')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();

       return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:Page:anagrafica.html.twig', array('anagrafiche' => $anagrafiche));
    }

}
```